# Hover state using box shadow inset in Chrome is 1px off

Tags: html, css

i'm using a box shadow on a hover state to create inbound borders on a table - I know in Chrome you have to actually do it differently than in Firefox. However there's 1px being cut off on the bottom on the hover state. The code is below. it's using datatables. Screen shot and code below (just for the row - since we're using SASS). Anyone have any ideas? Much appreciated. . I believe it's related to a box-shadow inset bug in chrome.  [image]

```
<table>
  <tr class="odd" role="row">
   <td data-title="Order Number">
    <td data-title="Business">Tommy Biz</td>
     <td data-title="Products">Logo Design, Standard Business Card</td>
       <td data-title="Reference Number">11-000198</td>
        <td data-title="Created By">Josh</td>
         <td data-title="Created On">08/15/2016 3:19 PM</td>
           <td data-title="Last Activity On">08/15/2016 3:19 PM</td>
           <td data-title="Status">Saved For Later</td>
         </tr>
    <table>
```

CSS (both regular and SASS which shows the actual "problematic" code)

```
table td::before {
display: none;
}
table td::before {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 0 none;
 content: attr(data-title);
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 8px;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 45%;
}
table tbody tr.group td, table th, table td::before, table.results th {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  border: 1px solid #d7dedb;
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

 table td {
   border: 1px solid #d7dedb;
   color: #757575;
   display: table-cell;
   font-size: 11px;
   padding: 5px 12px;
   position: static;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: auto;

%zebra-row {
  transition: background-color .1s ease-out;
  background-clip:padding-box;


 &:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: $alabaster;
}

 &:hover {
 background-color: $gallery;
 box-shadow: 2px 0 0 $aqua-forest inset;
}
/*For Chrome*/
 &:hover td:first-child {
box-shadow: 2px 0 0 $aqua-forest inset;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/okyfLf8x/1/   this seems to be working right though. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a table issue not a css issue. add the following to fix it.

in HTML

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

in CSS

```
table {border: none;}
```

this will remove the 1px off from the table and should get it to work. to give padding dont use `cellpadding` attribute on the table, instead give padding to the `td`'s in css.

here is a link for your fiddle fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/okyfLf8x/2/

Comment: thanks, I should have clarified this but in my code, it's set to zero. That was merely a rough way to imitate what was going on. I'll see what else I can find out.

Comment: I believe I fixed the issue throwing on a "border-bottom:none" rule along with the box-shadow. Fingers crossed

Comment: @erics15 the problem is that i cannot replicate it on the fiddle :/. good luck